# git merging conflicts on github

Tags: git

I have a branch that I am trying to merge into master
On github when I create a PR I get

```
Files changed 30
Conflicts on 5 files
```

Then I am trying to update my branch with master in order to resolve the conflicts.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my_branch
git merge master
[ ... resolve any conflicts ... ]
git add [files that were conflicted]
git commit
git push
```

Then I create a new PR and I get

```
files changed 50
```

How is that possible? Is there another way to resolve the conflicts?

Comment: When you see a huge number of files changed, one of the first things to check is if you have mistakenly auto-changed line-endings, whitespace, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a repository you share with other people? One possibility is that the extra changed files come from other people's changes. If that's the case, maybe that shouldn't bother you - just create your PR, making sure your code incorporates the latest master and resolves any merge conflicts.

(This should probably be a comment but I cannot comment on questions yet)